# How to initailize byte array of 100 bytes in java with all 0's

Tags: java

How to initialize byte array of 100 bytes in java with all 0's.
I want to create 100 byte array and initialize it with all 0's

Answer (score 118, accepted):

A new byte array will automatically be initialized with all zeroes. You don't have to do anything.

The more general approach to initializing with other values, is to use the `Arrays` class.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

byte[] bytes = new byte[100];
Arrays.fill( bytes, (byte) 1 );
```

Comment: The `Arrays.fill` is redundant unless you suspect you have altered the contents of the array.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I realize this, and I think it's clear from the other 5 answers that say exactly that. However for people landing here from a search, they might want to initialize it with 1s or something else.

Comment: @wolfcastle You are right, but why not state it clearer in your answer. For example adding a comment: "The bytes has been initialized to 0, but if you want to initialize it to something else, such as 1, then Arrays.fill(bytes, (byte)1);

Answer (score 38):

Simply create it as `new byte[100]` it will be initialized with 0 by default

Answer (score 21):

```
byte [] arr = new byte[100]
```

Each element has 0 by default.

You could find  primitive default values [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html):

```
Data Type   Default Value
byte        0
short       0
int         0
long        0L
float       0.0f
double      0.0d
char        '\u0000'
boolean     false
```

Answer (score 9):

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[100];
```

Initializes all byte elements with default values, which for byte is 0. In fact, all elements of an array when constructed, are initialized with default values for the array element's type.

Answer (score 3):

The default element value of any array of primitives is already zero: `false` for booleans.

Answer (score 2):

Actually the default value of byte is 0.